# How to open live server vscode in other devices

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am using live server vscode on my device but I want other devices to have access to the ip address for me with a password.
So how i can do this?!

Answer (score 6):

1. Get your PC's IP address
2. Run Live Server
3. Open 2nd device's browser
4. Type your PC's IP address and the Live Server port, ex: `192.168.0.109:5500`

*If you are using windows and do everything correctly but it still doesn't work, you should disable the firewall or add a rule for this port*